# How to implement change the language In-App using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, kotlin-multiplatform

I saw many tutorials, but I couldn't find anything that could solve my problem.
Design and implementation of language change In-App with Jetpack Compose

I finished the Android developer site, but it did not explain the design method

Comment: This [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/app-languages) seems to be what you are looking for.

Comment: @ArthurKasparian I read this document, but unfortunately I could not get any results from it

Comment: Did you find any approach?